# Unoffical roms 4.0 or 4.1 for Galaxy Note?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 4.1-jelly-bean, rom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I've been over to XDA forums and am overwhelmed by the amount of information available. I am interested in getting 4.0 or 4.1 on to a Galaxy Note but don't really know where to start with the whole process. Currently the device is rooted and runs 2.3, but that's about it.

What options are there right now? The few I've found cautioned users strongly against using them at the risk of bricking a device. Obviously this is always a concern, but it seems to be mentioned far more on the Galaxy Note.

Any advice or links to unofficial roms or guides on how to get this going?

Comment: Pay attention to the infamous brick-bug (it's basically a faulty emmc chip if I got that right. You need to have a kernel that doesn't issue partition table formatting commands if you reflash (+ the rom you reflash must also not do this). Check IF you have a FAULTY nand chip first. http://www.xda-developers.com/tag/samsung-galaxy-note-gt-n7000/ Here's some more infor how to check if your device is affected: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1693704

Comment: Sorry you're having trouble, but we don't do ROM recommendations.  Check out the [FAQ] and feel free to ask any other questions you might have that would be a better fit here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at CyanogenMod 9. It's an ICS rom. I've tried a few roms on a few phones and I still think CyanogenMod is the best. I doubt there would be any decent JB roms yet, at least none that were in any way usable or stable.

Comment: Now I just need to find a simple step by step guide and I'll be set. :)

Comment: There is a thread on XDA developers about CM9 on the Galaxy Note. There is a quick guide on how to install it. If you've installed custom roms before you should be fine with that. If not, it probably looks very daunting as there isn't too much information. If I find a better guide I'll post it up here. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1627854

Comment: Cyanogenmod has very comprehensive howto's, here's the Galaxy Note one: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Note:_Full_Update_Guide TeamHacksung is responsible for the Galaxy series support for CM9, check their wiki, they also have guides: http://teamhacksung.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page (the note is 'N7000').